# issues with groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have the following groovy script that does the following
- checks all the builds for a specific job to see if it has the same build parameter as the current build
- stops the build with the same parameter as the current build

```
import hudson.tasks.Ant 

def myBuildNumber = build.getEnvVars()['BUILD_NUMBER'].toInteger();
def myFractureNO = build.getEnvVars()['FRACTURE_NO'].toInteger();


def projectXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText("curl http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/api/xml".execute().text);

projectXml.build.each {
  if(it.number.toInteger() < myBuildNumber)
  {
      def jobXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(("curl http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/" + it.number + "/api/xml").execute().text);

      def myparams = jobXml.getAction(hudson.model.ParametersAction.class);
      for( p in myparams ) {
            printlin p.name.toString();
           if (p.name.toString == "FRACTURE_NO") {
              if (p.value.toString() == myFractureNO.toString()) {
                "curl http://test.corp.adobe.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/" + it.number + "/stop".execute().waitFor();
                 break;
              }
          }
      }

   }
}
```

the script outputs a bunch of urls to the screen because of the line:

```
 def projectXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText("curl http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/api/xml".execute().text);
```

and it doesn't do what it suppose to do. How can I make it so that the line

```
 def projectXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText("curl http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/api/xml".execute().text);
```

doesn't output the urls to the screen?

I get the following output

> 189http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/189/188http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/188/187http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/187/186http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/186/185http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/185/184http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/184/183http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/183/182http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/182/181http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/181/179http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/179/178http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/178/177http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/177/176http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/176/174http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/174/173http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/173/172http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/172/171http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/171/170http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/170/169http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/169/168http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/168/167http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/167/166http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/166/165http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/165/164http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/164/163http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/163/162http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/162/161http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/161/160http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/160/159http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/159/158http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/158/157http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/157/156http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/156/155http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/155/154http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/154/153http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/153/152http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/152/151http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/151/150http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/150/148http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/148/146http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/146/144http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/144/143http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/143/142http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/142/141http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/141/140http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/140/139http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/139/138http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/138/137http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/137/136http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/136/135http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/135/134http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/134/133http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/133/132http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/132/131http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/131/130http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/130/129http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/129/128http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/128/127http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/127/126http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/126/125http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/125/124http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/124/123http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/123/122http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/122/121http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/121/120http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/120/119http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/119/118http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/118/117http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/117/116http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/116/115http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/115/114http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/114/113http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/113/112http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/112/111http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/111/110http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/110/109http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/109/108http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/108/107http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/107/106http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/106/105http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/105/104http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/104/103http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/103/102http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/102/101http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/101/100http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/100/99http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/99/98http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/98/97http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/97/96http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/96/95http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/95/94http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/94/93http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/93/92http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/92/91http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/91/90http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/90/89http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/89/88http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/88/87http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/87/86http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/86/85http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/85/

Why do I get the output above?

Comment: Is there a question in here somewhere? ;-)

Comment: I don't understand; you're calling `text` on your parsed XML, which returns a  string. Wouldn't you want to process it as the returned XML?

Comment: The string gets outputed to the console. I don't want the string to be outputted to the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you invoking curl at all? Just retrieve the contents of the URL from groovy:

```
def xmlString = new URL("http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/api/xml").getText()
def projectXML = new XMLSlurper().parseText(xmlString)
```

Comment: I still get the following output  189http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/189/188http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/188/187http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/187/186

Answer (score 1):

XmlSlurper can parse the URL directly:

```
def projectXml = new XmlSlurper().parse('http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/api/xml')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the output on screen is because of `curl`. So can try to silence it with `-s` or `--silent` option:

```
def projectXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText("curl -s 'http://test.corp.test.com:8080/job/FractureAUT/api/xml'".execute().text);
```

Comment: what is the output?